# parse_ini_file read a hidden file local win

Tags: php, ini

When I use a `parse_ini_file` function to read ini file works fine. But when I read a hidden ini file or system file:

> [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\wamp\www

When I create a ini file I use `file_put_contents` then I convert a file to hidden using this code:

```
system('attrib +s +h ' . escapeshellarg($filename));
```

How I can read a hidden file ?

Comment: This *should* have nothing to do with the fact that it's hidden. What's your PHP user, and what rights does that user have to the files?

Comment: $username = getenv("username"); in php info 'ALIPC$' , and the ini file Owner 'administrators'

Comment: hi please how can change user